# Allow adding errors and warnings and remove both after a while with seperate timers

Tags: c#, timer, blazor

I use this in my Blazor application, letting other services send errors or warnings to this AlertService. The service triggers an update of a component which simply displays the messages, errors in red warnings in yellow.
While getting no new warnings, the existing warnings should be deleted, every 5 seconds one less warning being displayed. Same goes for errors.
When a new warning comes in, the timer restarts (so when the service was 1 second before deleting a warning, that timer is now void and the new timer starts with 5 seconds again).

This is my class, I feel there must be a better way but I haven't figured it out yet:

```
    public class AlertService
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> errors = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> warnings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private object? talkingStickErrors;
    private object? talkingStickWarnings;

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> Errors { get; }

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> Warnings { get; }

    public AlertService()
    {
        Errors = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(errors);
        Warnings = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(warnings);
    }

    public void Error(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {message}");
        errors.Add(message);
        StartErrorTimer();
    }

    private void StartErrorTimer()
    {
        talkingStickErrors = new object();
        RemoveErrorAfterDelay(talkingStickErrors);
    }

    private async void RemoveErrorAfterDelay(object localTalkingStick)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            if (localTalkingStick != talkingStickErrors || !errors.Any()) return;
            errors.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }

    public void Warning(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Warning: {message}");
        warnings.Add(message);
        StartWarningTimer();
    }

    private void StartWarningTimer()
    {
        talkingStickWarnings = new object();
        RemoveWarningAfterDelay(talkingStickWarnings);
    }

    private async void RemoveWarningAfterDelay(object localTalkingStick)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            if (localTalkingStick != talkingStickWarnings || !warnings.Any()) return;
            warnings.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I couldn't think of a better word for the talking sticks. They're not exactly locks.

**Update**: No more talking sticks, it now just reused the last message it received.

**Update 2**: Talking sticks again, as string have no unique identity.

**Update 3**: Instead of an extra event, the alerts are now in ObservableCollections. I keep receiving stuff about encapsulation and Rx. ould appreciate someone helping me to DRY this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this collection to hold your messages. It should do exactly what you are looking for - just create couple instances for errors and warnings.

```
public class MessageCollection : ObservableCollection<string>
{
    public MessageCollection()
    {
        Timer = new Timer(Callback, this, 5000, 5000);
        CollectionChanged += MessageCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    Timer Timer { get; }

    void MessageCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Timer.Change(5000, 5000);
    }
    static void Callback(object state)
    {
        var that = (MessageCollection)state;
        if (that.Any())
        {
            that.CollectionChanged -= that.MessageCollection_CollectionChanged;
            that.RemoveAt(that.Count - 1);
            that.CollectionChanged += that.MessageCollection_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha I like it, will try this out. Wouldn't the `RemoveAt(Count-1)` remove the latest message though? I put RemoteAt(0) to always remove the oldest message. Also: why does it have to remove and readd the event handler? Isn't it the same object each iteration?

Comment: Ah also which Timer is this? I haven't found an async timer yet, and as this is running in a browser it definitely needs to be async.

Comment: MS just tells me both Timers.Timer and Threading.Timer are supposed to be used server-based and the others are just net Framework lol I feel a bit lost. Might have to build my own async timer.

Comment: Tried it, it works great, thanks! (I'm using the System.Threading.Timer)  Also I understand now that the callback removes/readds the callback so that the change doesn't trigger resetting the timer, and that the callback is static so it has to use `that`.